# What's going on with the Announcer badge?

Tags: bug, badges

The Announcer badge was recently awarded to a lot of users simultaneously, on several sites, e.g.:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer) at 2019-12-12 23:05:01Z
- [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/announcer) at 2019-12-12 23:55:12Z
- [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/announcer) at 2019-12-13 00:25:01Z